# How to rearrange fields in comment_form()

Tags: comments, templates, comment-form

Im using a custom filter to change the fields, but can´t figure out how to change the **order** of the fields in the comment form.

Desired order:

- comment field (first/top)
- name
- email
- website

This is the code which I am currently using:

```
function alter_comment_form_fields($fields){
    $fields['comments'] = 'Test';
    $fields['author'] = '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Your name, please' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="John Smith" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';
    $fields['email'] = 'next';  //removes email field
    //$fields['url'] = '';  //removes website field

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','alter_comment_form_fields');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's pretty simple. You just have to take the `textarea` out of the default fields – filter `'comment_form_defaults'` – and print it on the action `'comment_form_top'`:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Comment Textarea On Top
 * Description: Makes the textarea the first field of the comment form.
 * Version:     2012.04.30
 * License:     MIT
 * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

// We use just one function for both jobs.
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 't5_move_textarea' );
add_action( 'comment_form_top', 't5_move_textarea' );

/**
 * Take the textarea code out of the default fields and print it on top.
 *
 * @param  array $input Default fields if called as filter
 * @return string|void
 */
function t5_move_textarea( $input = array () )
{
    static $textarea = '';

    if ( 'comment_form_defaults' === current_filter() )
    {
        // Copy the field to our internal variable …
        $textarea = $input['comment_field'];
        // … and remove it from the defaults array.
        $input['comment_field'] = '';
        return $input;
    }

    print apply_filters( 'comment_form_field_comment', $textarea );
}
```

Comment: Good solution but what if you want to change the order of 3 or 4 fields?

Comment: @BradDalton The same: remove all field contents first, then print them in the desired order in `comment_form_top`.

Comment: Don't know if code had changed since then but for 4.0 it seems like `comment_form_before_fields` is better hook then `comment_form_top`

Comment: @MarkKaplun Nowadays I would pass the desired position as an argument to a class. :)

Answer (score 8):

There are obviously a number of ways to accomplish this. For example, to move the comment field to the bottom of the form you would use code like this:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'move_comment_field' );
function move_comment_field( $fields ) {
    $comment_field = $fields['comment'];
    unset( $fields['comment'] );
    $fields['comment'] = $comment_field;
    return $fields;
}
```

If you wanted to **rearrange all the fields**:

1. unset all the fields
2. put the fields back into the array but **in the order you want them displayed**

Simple right? I figured I'd spell it out explicitly for the next noobie like me to find this page and not find the answers useful.

Answer (score 5):

I liked toscho answer.
However I wanted to use a custom textarea, so it didn't work in that case.
I used the same hooks but with separate functions:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'remove_textarea' );
add_action( 'comment_form_top', 'add_textarea' );

function remove_textarea($defaults)
{
    $defaults['comment_field'] = '';
    return $defaults;
}

function add_textarea()
{
    echo '<p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="60" rows="6" placeholder="write your comment here..." aria-required="true"></textarea></p>';
}
```

Comment: Note that many anti-spam plugins are changing the textarea too. This has to be tested very good – I had serious problems with a similar approach.

Answer (score 2):

The exact CSS to do this will depend on your theme, however, here's one way:

```
#commentform {
display:table;
width:100%;   
}

.comment-form-comment {
display: table-header-group; 
}
```

The table display methods let you reorder things of arbitrary height.

More info: http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/

Comment: Great idea Otto. A [similar approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210655/43806) could be accomplished using flexbox: <br>`#commentform { display: flex; flex-flow: column; }`
`.comment-form-comment { order: -1; }`.

Answer (score 1):

the fields od comment form are in the array `$fields` in function [`comment_form()`](http://m.wpseek.com/?p=detail&s=comment_form). You can hook inside the filter `comment_form_default_fields` and [reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316916/php-function-to-reorder-an-array) the array.

Also you can hook inside filter `comment_form_defaults` and change the defaults; leave all data in array and change only the `field`of the array with your custom fields; include the html.

the default if $fields:

```
      $fields =  array(
          'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                      '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
          'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                      '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
          'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label>' .
                      '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
      );
```