# Edit Comment_Field while using T5 Comment Textarea On Top-Plugin

Tags: comments, comment-form

I’m using the [*T5 Comment Textarea On Top*-Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50598/73) for the comment_field. I’m a newbie to wordpress. So I don’t know, how can i edit the Style of the comment_field or edit the Label? Usually I would put in the array of comment_form in my comments.php like this:

```
   'comment_field'        => '<p class="comment-form-comment">...',
```

But this only adds another textarea. And then I tried to add a new filter like this:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'my_comment_form_field_comment' );

function my_comment_form_field_comment( $comment_field ) {

    $comment_field = '<div class="comment-field-wrapper">' . $comment_field . '</div>';

    return $comment_field;
}
```

...no changes. Sorry, seems a little bit like Trial’n’Error. Maybe you can help me out. Would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the textarea earlier than the plugin. The plugin runs with a default priority of 10, so you could use 9:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse_61103_change_textarea', 9 );

function wpse_61103_change_textarea( $fields )
{
    $fields['comment_field'] = '<div class="comment-field-wrapper">'
        . $fields['comment_field']
        . '</div>';

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! And how can I edit the label, the <texarea> etc.?

Comment: You can do with `$fields['comment_field']` what ever you want. My plugin just takes the code and moves it up, no matter what you did before.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand: I can wrap it up with the div. No problem. But I don't know where to put the Styles for the <textarea>. Or edit the field like this '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">'.

Comment: That’s the content of `$fields['comment_field']`. If you write `$fields['comment_field'] = 'hello'` in the function above then that is the new content.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, I’m betriebsblind. And thanks a lot!