# Comments - Ensure the correct field is highlighted for nested replies

Tags: comments, javascript

I've got my comments working great, well.... Just about Great!!!!

I'm a passionate UX guy doing my blog. I've got the comments form to beautifully reposition its self under neath a comment so that it does nested comments.

But I have one annoyance!

When someone hits the reply button the comment field is highlighted / focussed. From a user's point of view this is wrong as it should be the first field that should be highlighted or none at all!

Do you guys have any thoughts on how one could fix it so that when a user does reply that the comment field isn't the one that gets highlighted?

- Solution 1 would be just show the form - Don't highlight / focus on any fields
- Solution 2 would be highlight the first field in the form

Would love to know your thoughts, on how I can achieve either.

Comment: The best option is, in my opinion, to [move the textarea to top](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50598/73), because the user has already started to formulate the reply in her mind.

Comment: This is a little more generic UX in this form. Might make sense on [ux.se] for decision _what_ to do, then back here on _how_ to do it. :)