# is it possible to get the hook name in add_action?

Tags: hooks, actions

given this:

```
<?php add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args ); ?>
```

Is there a way to get `$hook` value inside the function `$function_to_add`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the current hook is always `current_filter()`. Despite its name, this function returns the name of actions too.

Usage example: [Move the textarea in a comment form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50598/73).

The current priority is: `key( $GLOBALS['wp_filter'][ $hook ] )`.

Comment: @Reigel ... and then there's the [`current_action`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.1/src/wp-includes/plugin.php#L361) wrapper for those who find it strange to use `current_filter` in action callbacks ;-)