# WP comments form (custom) is displaying an extra comment field

Tags: comments, comment-form

I am building a custom WordPress theme and I'm trying to tweak the comments form. If you go to [my blog page](http://digitalbrent.com/blog/) and scroll down to the comments section (bottom of each entry) you'll notice that the comments section has two `textarea` fields. I don't want the first one, but I'm not sure why or how it's getting inserted in there. I'd like the order of the form to just be: name, email, comment. The code for the extra text area is not in the code I've written for the custom comment form in functions.php:

```
function alpha_comments_defaults($defaults){
    $defaults['id_form'] = '';
    $defaults['id_submit'] = '';

    return $defaults;
}

function alpha_comments_fields(){
    $commenter= wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req = get_option('require_name_email');
    $aria_req = ($req ? " aria-required='true'" : ' ');

    $fields =  array(

        'author' =>
            '<p class="comment-form-author"><label>' . __( 'Name', 'domainreference' ) . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
            '<input name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" ' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

        'email' =>
            '<p class="comment-form-email"><label>' . __( 'Email', 'domainreference' ) .  ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
            '<input name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" ' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

        'url' =>
            '',

        'comment_field' =>
            '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label>' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label>' .
            '<textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" ' . $aria_req . '></textarea></p>'
    );

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'alpha_comments_defaults');
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'alpha_comments_fields');
```

How do I get rid of the extra form field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that WordPress handles the comment field separately than the other fields. If you look at `comment_form()` in `wp-includes/comment-template.php`, you can see this.

It's possible to set `$defaults['comment_field']` to false in `alpha_comments_defaults()` then add the comment field markup to `$fields['comment_field']` in `alpha_comments_fields()` in the desired order, but this could cause trouble with plugins.

I've moved things around and added code to handle the field ordering that you requested.

```
function alpha_comments_defaults( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['id_form'] = '';
    $defaults['id_submit'] = '';
    $defaults['comment_field'] = '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label>' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label>' .
                                                                '<textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>';
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'alpha_comments_defaults');


function alpha_comments_fields( $fields ) {
    $commenter= wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : ' ' );

    $fields = array(
                        'author' =>
                                '<p class="comment-form-author"><label>' . __( 'Name', 'domainreference' ) . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                                '<input name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" ' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

                        'email' =>
                                '<p class="comment-form-email"><label>' . __( 'Email', 'domainreference' ) .  ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label> ' .
                                '<input name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" ' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',

                        'url' => '',
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'alpha_comments_fields');


// Reorder comment fields.
// http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218324/2807
function alpha_move_comment_field( $fields ) {
    $comment_field = $fields['comment'];
    unset( $fields['comment'] );
    $fields['comment'] = $comment_field;

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'alpha_move_comment_field' );
```